# More efficient way to find the model with the lowest AIC?

Tags: r, aic, poisson-regression, zero-inflation, information-criteria

I am working on the zero-inflated Poisson model with a dataset, and trying to find a combination of variables that yields the lowest AIC. I used a series of for loops in R, but it takes forever to get the results. Is there another way that is more efficient in terms of time? Or, should I use a program other than R?

```
install.packages("pscl")
require(pscl)

data <- read.csv("data.csv")
var_names <- names(data[1:ncol(data)])

f <- function(var_names){
  lowest_aic <- Inf     
  best_model <- NULL    
  
  for(i in 1:length(var_names)){
    var_count_list <- combn(var_names,i)
    
    for(j in 1:ncol(var_count_list)){
      var_count <-var_count_list[,j]
    
      for(k in 1:length(var_names)){
        var_zinf_list <- combn(var_names,k)
      
        for(l in 1:ncol(var_zinf_list)){
          var_zinf <-var_zinf_list[,l]
      
          model <- zeroinfl(as.formula(paste(paste("dep_var ~", paste(var_count,collapse="+")),paste(var_zinf, collapse="+"),sep="|")), data = data)
          
          if(AIC(model) < lowest_aic){ 
            lowest_aic <- AIC(model)   
            best_model <- model        
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(best_model)
}

f(var_names)
```

Comment: Performance is really a secondary concern here. You should first explain why you are doing this. It looks like data dredging which is a ill-advised practice.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your comment. I am using both theory-driven approach and model-based approach. My goal here is to see if the results from these two approach are consistent.